# Differentiate a user function in sympy?

Tags: sympy

Does sympy have the concept of user defined functions?  For example, I want to write a method that takes a two-argument function, and returns the derivative with respect to the first argument.  For example:

```
mydiff = ...
mydiff(atan2) # returns f(y, x) -> x / (x^2 + y^2)
g(a, b) = a*a*b # This syntax doesn't work, what syntax does work?
mydiff(g) # returns h(a, b) -> 2 a b
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is a `Lambda`:

```
In [64]: Lambda((y, x), atan2(y, x).diff(y))                                                                                                   
Out[64]: 
            x   
(y, x) ↦ ───────
          2    2
         x  + y
```

Comment: Thanks!  Although a `Lambda` is an `Expr`, not a `Function`, so it doesn't have methods like `diff` and `fdiff`.